# I want to get budgets list of logged-in user in my service. How to get username from principals

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security, jwt

I have my money tracking service, and I need a logged-in user to see only their own data, budgets, and transactions. What's the best way to achieve this? I was thinking of adding 'principal' as an argument to all endpoints and retrieving everything based on the username. I tried to make smth but it was without any succes.

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("api/v1/budgets")
public class BudgetController {

    private final ModelMapper modelMapper;
    private final BudgetService budgetService;

    public BudgetController(ModelMapper modelMapper, BudgetService budgetService) {
        this.modelMapper = modelMapper;
        this.budgetService = budgetService;
    }

    @GetMapping
    public ResponseEntity<List<BudgetDTO>> getBudgets(Principal principal){


        String loggedInUsername = principal.getName();

        List<BudgetDTO> budgetsDto = budgetService.getBudgetsByCreatedBy(loggedInUsername, 5, 5).stream().map(budget -> modelMapper.map(budget, BudgetDTO.class))
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
        return new ResponseEntity<List<BudgetDTO>>(budgetsDto, HttpStatus.OK);
    }
```

```
@Repository
public interface BudgetRepo extends JpaRepository<Budget, Long> {
    Page<BudgetDTO> findByUserId(Long userId, Pageable page);
}

public ArrayList<BudgetDTO> getBudgetsByCreatedBy(String username, int page, int size) {
        User user = userRepo.getUserByUsername(username);
        Pageable pageable = PageRequest.of(page, size, Sort.Direction.DESC, "goal");
        Page<BudgetDTO> budgets = budgetRepo.findByUserId(user.getId(), pageable);
        return new ArrayList<BudgetDTO>(budgets.getContent());
    }
```

[image: I didn't get any data]

Comment: `What's the best way to achieve this?` is an opinion. Opinion based questions are not allowed on stack overflow. What is best? based on what criteria?

Answer (score -1):

you can modify the Controller method like

```
@GetMapping
public ResponseEntity<List<BudgetDTO>> getBudgets(@AuthenticationPrincipal Principal principal){
        UserEntity loggedInUser = (UserEntity)principal;
        List<BudgetDTO> budgetsDto = budgetService.getBudgetsByCreatedBy(loggedInUser.getName(), 5, 5).stream().map(budget -> modelMapper.map(budget, BudgetDTO.class))
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
        return new ResponseEntity<List<BudgetDTO>>(budgetsDto, HttpStatus.OK);
    }
}
```